# readdir() attempted on invalid dirhandle

Tags: perl, cgi, opendir

What am I doing wrong? I've tried many things but can't seem to read from this file. Thanks!

```
my $d = 'URLs.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $d)
#opendir(D, "$d") || die "Can't open directory $d: $!\n";
  or die "Can't open directory $d: $!\n";

my @list = readdir($fh);
closedir($fh);

foreach my $f (@list) {


my $json_data = get "$f";
my $json_obj = new JSON;
my $URLdata = $json_obj->decode($json_data);

  return $URLdata->{'status'} eq 'UP';
}
```

Comment: `$fh` is a filehandle, not a dirhandle (as the error message says). You can't `readdir` on a filehandle. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @MattJacob: Warnings aren't enabled, so no error message.

Answer (score 5):

`URLs.txt` appears to be a file, not a directory

To open a ***file***, write

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!;
```

and read from it with

```
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) { ... }
```

To open a ***directory***, write

```
opendir my $dh, $dirname or die $!;
```

and read its contents with

```
while ( my $item = readdir $dh ) { ... }
```

If you had `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place as you should in every Perl program you write you would have seen

> readdir() attempted on invalid dirhandle $fh
>   closedir() attempted on invalid dirhandle $fh

which would have guided you towards the problem

You may be better of with other functions, depending on what it is you want to do

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names are not great, to put it mildly. Let's fix that!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use LWP::Simple;

my $file = 'URLs.txt';

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file) or die "Can't open file $file: $!\n";
chomp(my @lines = <$fh>);
close($fh);

foreach my $url (@lines) {
    my $json_text = get($url);

    if (defined($json_text)) {
        my $perl_ref = decode_json($json_text);

        if ($perl_ref->{status} eq 'UP') {
            print "foo\n";
        }
    } else {
        # handle the error!
    }
}
```

You'll notice I also:

- Added `use strict` and `use warnings`, which should be in every Perl file you write
- Added error-checking to the LWP `get()` result
- Removed indirect object notation (`new JSON`) in favor of the `decode_json()` convenience function. It's the same as `JSON->new->utf8->decode()`, only shorter.
- Removed the `return` statement, because it doesn't make any sense outside of a subroutine. If this code has actually been yanked from a subroutine, then you should show that as part of your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your response! What I am trying to do is call this perl script from another javascript and return the boolean. Do you know if this is possible?